# SAPUI5 use value from JSON Model 1 in JSON Model 2

Tags: sapui5, jsonmodel

Can I use/bind a value from a first JSON Model in a second JSON Model?
In the example below the text of the first item in the second model (MyNamedModel) should be 'Apple'.

Complete example can be found here: https://plnkr.co/edit/WtStoqxsjUAfC9Ia

```
var oFruits = {
    first: "Apple",
    second: "Banana"
  }
  var oFruitModel = new JSONModel(oFruits);
  this.getView().setModel(oFruitModel, "FruitModel");

    var oData = {
      "items": [
        {   Key: "A",
            Text: "{path: '/FruitModel>/first'}",
            Icon: "sap-icon://nutrition-activity"
        },
        {   Key: "B",
            Text: "Paper Plane",
            Icon: "sap-icon://paper-plane"
        },
        {   Key: "C",
            Text: "Vacation",
            Icon: "sap-icon://general-leave-request"
        }
      ]
    };

    var oMyModel = new JSONModel(oData);
    this.getView().setModel(oMyModel, "MyNamedModel");
```

Use case:
In reality I have a geoMap control where the mapConfiguration is in a JSONModel and I would like to get one specific parameter value (URL) from the backend and use it in the mapConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can bind it.
For the following example, it will look like this:

```
var oData = {
          "items": [
            {   Key: "A",
          //  Text: "Apple",
            Text: this.getView().getModel("FruitModel").getData().first,
            Icon: "sap-icon://nutrition-activity"
            }
          ]
        };
```

Basically with the statement `this.getView().getModel("FruitModel").getData()` you receive  access to the whole structure from the "FruitModel". Furthere one, you may assign it's values whatever you'd like to.

Here is also your working example https://plnkr.co/edit/7EO3qaXPpHX5QUZM